# Combine summary and nrow

Tags: r, function, matrix, vector, summary

I'm trying to create a function that will find summary and number of rows, so first I'm trying to create something like this:

```
G <- summary(mtcars)
H <- nrow(mtcars)
I <- ("# of Rows")
J <- (c(I,H))
K <- print(G,J)
K
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
Error in format.default(unclass(x), digits = digits, justify = justify) : 

invalid 'digits' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In format.default(unclass(x), digits = digits, justify = justify) :
 NAs introduced by coercion
> K
Error: object 'K' not found
```

What I want to get is this:

```
         V1         
 Min.     :  19.35  
 1st Qu.  :  61.22  
 Median   : 126.76  
 Mean     : 212.96  
 3rd Qu.  : 158.13  
 Max.     : 1500.00  
 # of Rows: 367
```

Obviously I'm way off here, but I cant seem to get my matrix and vectors to work together.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your question is actually not clear without a reproducible example. Do you expect the function to only work with one-column data.frames?

Comment: I apologize, added example. Thought it was clear before, obviously was wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
> print(rbind(summary(mtcars), paste0("Rows.  :", nrow(mtcars))), quote = FALSE)
      mpg             cyl             disp             hp             drat             wt       
 Min.   :10.40   Min.   :4.000   Min.   : 71.1   Min.   : 52.0   Min.   :2.760   Min.   :1.513  
 1st Qu.:15.43   1st Qu.:4.000   1st Qu.:120.8   1st Qu.: 96.5   1st Qu.:3.080   1st Qu.:2.581  
 Median :19.20   Median :6.000   Median :196.3   Median :123.0   Median :3.695   Median :3.325  
 Mean   :20.09   Mean   :6.188   Mean   :230.7   Mean   :146.7   Mean   :3.597   Mean   :3.217  
 3rd Qu.:22.80   3rd Qu.:8.000   3rd Qu.:326.0   3rd Qu.:180.0   3rd Qu.:3.920   3rd Qu.:3.610  
 Max.   :33.90   Max.   :8.000   Max.   :472.0   Max.   :335.0   Max.   :4.930   Max.   :5.424  
 Rows.  :32      Rows.  :32      Rows.  :32      Rows.  :32      Rows.  :32      Rows.  :32     
      qsec             vs               am              gear            carb      
 Min.   :14.50   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :3.000   Min.   :1.000  
 1st Qu.:16.89   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:3.000   1st Qu.:2.000  
 Median :17.71   Median :0.0000   Median :0.0000   Median :4.000   Median :2.000  
 Mean   :17.85   Mean   :0.4375   Mean   :0.4062   Mean   :3.688   Mean   :2.812  
 3rd Qu.:18.90   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:4.000   3rd Qu.:4.000  
 Max.   :22.90   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :5.000   Max.   :8.000  
 Rows.  :32      Rows.  :32       Rows.  :32       Rows.  :32      Rows.  :32
```

I'm not really sure why it is useful to have that quantity for each variable given that the number of observations in each vector in a data.frame is (by definition) constant, but there it is.

Comment: Thanks, for the solution. I should have specified that my data only had one vector. Now I can go and figure out what rbind, and quote does (i.e. learn to fish).